Laravel 11 Reverb : BroadcastException: Pusher Error (Not found)
In my local pc its working fine.
But in production (Apache server) its giving the BroadcastException Pusher Error (Not found) when triggering any event
REVERB_APP_ID=401372 
REVERB_APP_KEY=vcgwou45dwfj3qek4ixsv 
REVERB_APP_SECRET=o1jvqub6yshtowosmgbz 
REVERB_HOST="sub.doamin.com" 
REVERB_PORT=443 
REVERB_SCHEME=https

#REVERB_SERVER_HOST="0.0.0.0" 
#REVERB_SERVER_PORT=8080

VITE_REVERB_APP_KEY="${REVERB_APP_KEY}" 
VITE_REVERB_HOST="${REVERB_HOST}" 
VITE_REVERB_PORT="${REVERB_PORT}" 
VITE_REVERB_SCHEME="${REVERB_SCHEME}"

php artisan rverb:start --debug
Starting server on 0.0.0.0:8080 (sub.domain.com) 
Connection Established.....

But when triggering the event it gives BroadcastException;
broadcast(new FriendRequestReceived($sender, $receiver));
public function broadcastOn(): array { 
   return [ new PrivateChannel("friend-request.{$this->receiver->id}"), ]; 
}

on my vhost 443 config
ProxyPass /app  ws://0.0.0.0:8080/app
ProxyPassReverse /app ws://0.0.0.0:8080/app


Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastException: Pusher error:   404 Not Found  Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server.  Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) Server at sub.domain.com Port 443

vhost:
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Location /app>
        ProxyPass ws://0.0.0.0:8080/app
        ProxyPassReverse ws://0.0.0.0:8080/app
</Location>
<Location /apps>
        ProxyPass http://0.0.0.0:8080/apps
        ProxyPassReverse http://0.0.0.0:8080/apps
</Location>

It's worked

Thanks @Tho
This helps me a lot
One thing can you answer ?
I need to use this socket server for my flutter app so that i can make communication between my laravel app and flutter app
is there any way to do this ?
